# How to remotely query status of schedule task

Tags: windows

I was trying to get schedule task status from a remote server using the following:

schtasks /query /s \servername

and I got back something like:
ERROR:  A device attached to the system is not functioning.

I thought I might get something like:

You don't have permission

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
schtasks /query /s YourRemoteServer /fo list /tn "YourTaskName"
```

For more options type schtasks/? in cmd.

[image]

Comment: I tried it and resulted in incorrect syntax for /tn.  There is no tn switch for query option.

Comment: @bach ..Wrong..! `/tn` switch is there. type `schtasks /query /?` in your cmd. Can you please give the full path before YourTaskName and then try and also put the error message screenshot in question.

Comment: My system is xp and server 2003 and the /TN switch was not on the list.  What I did was very simple:  schtasks /query /s remoteServerName.  And that does not even work.  It works for local machine, but not remote.  Maybe it could not get through the firewall